# Processed withdrawal not reflecting in my blockchain wallet

Tags: transactions

Given below are the transaction details for the transaction which is not reflecting in my blockchain wallet,

Transaction batch :f28888630e090d083ce2be5658f526b148d3e8259a33bbcfa58063cc13e8a4c0

wallet address : 1NUf8TSGw5nuDpUre42n927dKhpDmeMdTo

Please note that i have some bitcoins before from 1HG43hWnE7ZZAcbhA3umYxB7JgPU99kATJ using the same wallet. So for the above transaction i just took the above wallet address and forward it to the one who was supposed to send me other bitcoins.

The transaction is showing on the blockchain explorer but it hasnot reflected in my blockchain wallet.

Please kindly assist, how can i recover the bitcoins if possible.

Kushie

Answer (score 1):

The [transaction](https://chainz.cryptoid.info/btc/tx.dws?f28888630e090d083ce2be5658f526b148d3e8259a33bbcfa58063cc13e8a4c0.htm) shows for me. If it doesn't show for you, perhaps your wallet is out of sync or on the wrong chain. Easy thing to try is to restart the wallet.